# In the Overlord LN, how did Shelltear get mind controlled? And by whom?

Tags: overlord

I read the Overlord LN, but I don't understand how Shelltear got-mind controlled. And who mind-controlled her?

It happens in volume 3, chapter 2, part 4.

Comment: I'm not going to write a full answer because I don't have the exact facts in mind, but volume 7's intermission partly answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Her name was Lady Kaire**, but she was injured before she could completely take control of Shalltear and left her in the regular enemy NPC state *(I don't do anything until something attacks me mode)*. As for what she used, in Yggdrasil **it would have been a world-level item, but I'm sure they're going to have their own name for it in this new world.** PS: World-level items basically make hacks look like child's play, so **it was most likely a really long incantation.**

Citation: All of this information is available in the last episode of Overlord, on Funimation, a legal site, with reliable translations. Episode 13, the episode in question, is available for everyone to watch, although you will need an account to prove you're 17 or older.  At 19:03, Lady Kaire and what she did is explained by a kneeling knight.  The fact that it is a world level item is said earlier on in the anime by Ains.